# How to parse json data and load it in the Listview

Tags: android, json, listview, android-volley

I am getting a json object from the api, I want to parse this json object and get the text value. I am using volley library and need to load it in listiew adapter.The json is object-array-object type.This is my Json object. Can you please help.

```
{"result":[{"id":"1","ExpendName":"rice","Cost":"500","Dates":"2018-01-09 11:13:58"},{"id":"2","ExpendName":"Meat","Cost":"550","Dates":"2018-01-09 11:17:27"},{"id":"3","ExpendName":"Fish","Cost":"250","Dates":"2018-01-09 11:21:30"},{"id":"4","ExpendName":"Pant","Cost":"700","Dates":"2018-01-09 11:36:45"},{"id":"5","ExpendName":"Shirt","Cost":"1000","Dates":"2018-01-09 11:50:11"},{"id":"6","ExpendName":"Tea","Cost":"55","Dates":"2018-01-09 13:37:42"},{"id":"7","ExpendName":"Lunch, Tea, Transport ","Cost":"750","Dates":"2018-01-09 13:41:29"},{"id":"8","ExpendName":"Breakfast ","Cost":"30","Dates":"2018-01-10 05:34:07"},{"id":"9","ExpendName":"Train","Cost":"460","Dates":"2018-01-11 05:32:42"},{"id":"10","ExpendName":"Bus","Cost":"1250","Dates":"2018-01-11 05:33:11"},{"id":"11","ExpendName":"Train","Cost":"500","Dates":"2018-01-11 10:03:00"}]}
```

Comment: Well, have you considered researching before posting this question?

Comment: I have searced and tried a lot. but there is problem using jsonobject in jsonobject request. That's why I am seeking help now.

Answer (score 0):

You would normally parse the data this way:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(rawData);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject mealObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = mealObject.getString("id");
        String expendName = mealObject.getString("ExpendName");
        String cost = mealObject.getString("Cost");
        String date = mealObject.getString("Dates");

        //Do whatever you want with the data
     }
 } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: Here "rawData" is it the "response" of Json object?

Comment: It's the JSON data that you posted above. `rawData` is the `String` object storing the above JSON response.

Comment: See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android) for more information on parsing JSON

Comment: It shows error in  this line as I requested json object request `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);` Can you please help!!

Comment: `final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {@Overridepublic void onResponse(JSONObject response)`

Comment: Here `response` is a `JSONObject`. You can do `JSONObject jsonObject = response;` in the above code and everything else remain be same.

Comment: It is showing error, Would you check it.
`try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response;
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject mealObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Dataset dataSet = new Dataset();
                        dataSet.setName(mealObject.getString("ExpendName"));
                        dataSet.setWorth(mealObject.getInt("Cost"));
                        list.add(dataSet);
                    }`

Comment: Yes, the code should be like this along with the `catch` block

Comment: How do you expect help when you are not clear about the error message you are getting? It's not a site having magicians